# How to compare values from 1 collection to another collection

Tags: c#, .net

I want to have functionality where I can compare one collection object to another collection object. Having the ability to compare the values within these types.

For example:

```
var users = new List<string>();
users.Add("James");
users.Add("Jim");
users.Add("Aaron");
users.Add("Mary");

var confirmedUsers = new List<string>();
confirmedUsers.Add("James");
confirmedUsers.Add("Jim");
```

I want the ability to compare these 2 lists and see the similarities and differences. e.g. functionality should display "James in both" - "Aaron missing from confirmedUsers" etc. Ps the type could be anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) and [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0)

```
//James, Jim
var intersect = users.Intersect(confirmedUsers);

//Aaron, Mary
var except = users.Except(confirmedUsers);
```

Comment: @user19329953 FYI - the default comparer is case sensitive so `Mary` and `mary` are two different strings

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that this works only with primitive types. If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface or `IEqualityComparer<T>` in a helper class. [Enumerable.Intersect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0)